# Exporting the fields of non-related with the model (Django Import-Export)

Tags: python, django, export, relationship, django-import-export

I am using Django-import-export on django admin.
I want to export the fields that are not related or are related over 2~3 relationship with the current model.

For example

```
Model Classes
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default=False)
    category= models.CharField(default=True)

class B(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(default=False)
    category = models.CharField(default=False)

Resource
class ResourceA(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = A
```

**How can I get the fields on ResourceA, so that I can export the them to excel?**

Comment: If the models are not related how do you propose to link them? You can add `fields` to a `ModelResource` and fields can span relationships `foreignkey__field`

Comment: It was related in fact, but the fields didn't related directly as Foreign or m2m, they are related 2 or 3 over.
I imported them with import_data workflow, but wondering how to export them...